# should all struct types be included in same header file?

Tags: c, struct

Below is a part of my small project.
[image]
I made a code just in one file(main.c) at the first time. And what i want to do now is to sepearte this file according to the function, which is called "modulation"(hope it is right). So, I have made a header file of each '.c', but i want to know how to deal with all typedef definition of struct.
Do I have to create new heade file named "struct.h" and put all of them in altogether?. Or each of this should be included just in the file where it is used?

Comment: I normally generate a separate header file for each data item (struct/union/tables/etc)  then if something needs changing, I have a small simple file to modify.    Generally, a file is broken into sub files for several reasons. 1) the main file is unwieldy large, 2) to help implement the traits of good programming, such as data hiding, implementation hiding, localization of functionality, limiting scope, re usability, code clarity, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is a matter of opinion.  Any of these approaches are valid, and will have their proponents and opponents:

1. Use  a separate header file for each struct.  This is very clear, but maybe lots of files.
2. Use a single header for all structs.  Sort of clear in its own way, but could get too big.
3. Use separate headers as in (1) but add a "master" header which `#include`s them all, for "convenience.  I think this is a bad idea, but lots of people do it.
4. Organize by theme, e.g. put all the "person"-related structs in one header.  If you want to do this, it's helpful if the "thematic" struct type names share some prefixes, e.g. "personId" and "personName".